# how to get static UISearchBar in xCode 5

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, xcode5

I have an app with this scene:

UIViewController:

- UISearchBar
- UITableView

that's the structure, inside of my UIViewController I have both components separated for allowing to have my searchBar at the top of the scene and fixed (always on top), and then my tableView, I did that in case the rows of my table were long enough to exceed my screen height

screenshot (iOS6):

[image]

the thing is... I just updated my xCode to latest version (xCode 5), and since UINavigationBar is semi-transparent, I get my searchBar back of NavigationController overlaping it.

screenshot (iOS7):

[image]

the thing is... I want that screen compatible for both versions (iOS6X, iOS7)

how do I do that???

thanks in advance for the help

---

---

**EDIT** all I had to do is to switch the translucent property of UINavigationBar to False, this is my method:

```
-(void)showSplitViewControllerInView:(UIView *)view
             withDetailViewController:(id)rightViewController{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard        = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle: nil];

    UINavigationController  *leftNavController;
    UINavigationController  *rightNavController;

    MainMenuVC  *leftViewController     = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenuVC"];

    leftNavController                   = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftViewController];
    rightNavController                  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rightViewController];

    leftNavController.toolbarHidden                 = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbarHidden                = FALSE;
    leftNavController.navigationBar.translucent     = FALSE;
    rightNavController.navigationBar.translucent    = FALSE;
    leftNavController.toolbar.translucent           = FALSE;
    rightNavController.toolbar.translucent          = FALSE;

    UISplitViewController   *splitViewController    = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers             = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNavController, rightNavController, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate        = rightViewController;

    view.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
}
```

the key is here:

```
    leftNavController.navigationBar.translucent     = FALSE;
    rightNavController.navigationBar.translucent    = FALSE;
```

Final Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the iOS6/7 Deltas feature of Xcode 5 to set your views correctly for iOS7 in IB and then deltas to position correctly in iOS6.

Comment: I've added 20.0 pixels of DeltaHeight, DeltaY in searchBar and TableView by using the visual editor, but nothing happens, I must say I disabled autolayout while I was using Xcode 4.6 because it's easier for me to design this way...

Comment: Autolayout is not necessary. Why did you add 20 pixel delta? Try adding 64: 20 status bar + 44 navigation bar.

Comment: going to give you the point because it's the right answer, but it seems it doesn't work for me since I'm adding my initial SplitViewController programmatically :(

Comment: If you layout the master and detail view controllers in a nib, it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: my issue was about a translucent UINavBar, all I had to do is to switch it to FALSE going to post the answer

Comment: I am not sure this is the result you REALLY want. It seems people are recommending opaque navigation bars and toolbars, but that should not be the default quick fix. Do a little more work, keep the translucency.